# Different definitions of local complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I cannot figure out (nor find a reference) whether the following statement is true or false.

Let $X$ be an excellent projective variety enjoying the property of being a local complete intersection (each local ring is the quotient of a regular local ring by an ideal generated by a regular sequence). Then there exists an immersion $\iota : X \rightarrow Y$ such that the ambient space $Y$ is regular and $X$ is a local complete intersection inside $Y$.

By saying that $X$ is a local complete intersection inside $Y$, I mean to say that there exists a locally free sheaf $\mathscr{E}$ of rank $r$ on Y together with a global section $s \in H^0(Y, \mathscr{E})$ such that the associated Koszul complex

$$ 0 \rightarrow \wedge^r \mathscr{E}^{\vee} \rightarrow ... \rightarrow \wedge^2 \mathscr{E}^{\vee} \rightarrow \wedge^1 \mathscr{E}^{\vee} \xrightarrow{s} \mathscr{O}_Y \rightarrow 0 $$

is quasi-isomorphic to $\iota_* \mathscr{O}_X$ via the natural map.

Intuitively, this condition requires $s$ to be a regular section of $\mathscr{E}$ cutting out $X$ inside $Y$ of codimension $r$.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27197/local-complete-intersections-which-are-not-complete-intersections

Comment: I don't think the question you link is relevant to this one. My understanding is that the counterexample provided in the link is not a global complete intersection in affine space. However, in this question, I am free to restrict to a smaller affine neighborhood.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I little more relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4921

Comment: This is very interesting. I will have a read. Thank you!

Comment: I wasn't aware of this local obstruction. I will change my question accordingly. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: What do you mean, "excellent"? The local rings of a projective variety are always excellent.

Comment: Even if it defined over a ring?

Comment: "variety" usually means "scheme of finite type over a field", or some further strengthening thereof ((geometrically) integral, separated, ...). However if $X$ is projective (more generally, locally of finite type) over an excellent base then it's also excellent.