# Geometric interpretation of normalization inside a finite extension of function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$Suppose $X = \Spec A$ is a smooth affine variety over $\mathbb C$ and suppose $L/K$ is a finite extension of its function field. Let $Y = \Spec B$, where $B$ is the set of elements of $L$ which are integral over $A$. Is there a simple geometric/explicit description of $Y\to X$ if we know the field extension explicitly? This is a somewhat vague question so let me given an example of a kind of answer that I would consider geometric/explicit.

Suppose we know that $L$ is obtained by adjoining to $K$ a root of some irreducible polynomial $f\in K[t]$, i.e., we have $L \simeq K[t]/(f)$ as field extensions of $K$. Then, can we geometrically describe $Y\to X$ in terms of this $f$? If this is something well-known, a reference would be very much appreciated.

Comment: TeX note: `\operatorname` adds operator spacing automatically, so you can use $\operatorname{Spec} A$ `\operatorname{Spec} A` instead of $\text{Spec }A$ `\text{Spec }A`.  If you will use an operator repeatedly, then you can define it once and for all as `\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Short answer: Yes. In general $Y$ will be an $[L:F]$-sheeted branched cover of $X$. The points $p \in X$ where $f(p) \in \mathbb C[t]$ has repeated roots are the branching set, with the branching dictated by how these roots merge. The simplest nontrivial example to keep in mind is an (affine open of a) hyperelliptic curve branched over $\mathbb A^1$, with $f = t^2 - (x-x_1)\cdots (x-x_n)$, where $\{x_i\}$ are the branch points.

Comment: @KevinCasto: It can be more subtle that that. If $A=\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $f=t^2-x(x-1)^2$, then a double root occurs at $x=0$ and $x=1$, but the normalization is $\operatorname{Spec}(A[u]/(u^2-x))$ (setting $u=t/(x-1)$) which is ramified only at $0$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks for the comment. The two examples so far in the comments are actually of monic polynomials $f\in A[t]$, so it seems one could at least probably think of $B$ as the normalization of the "first approximation" $A[t]/(f)$ which is finite over $A$. Is there a simple example to keep in mind what happens when $f$ is not already a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$?

Comment: @MohanSwaminathan: How about $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $f=xt-y$?

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Isn't the field extension trivial here, i.e., $L = K$? So, it seems $B = A$ in this case (since $A$ is already integrally closed in its function field). On the other hand, $f = xt^2 - y$ satisfies the requirement of producing a non-trivial extension and not being monic in $A[t]$ but this field extension seems to equivalently be described by $f = t^2 - xy$, so we're back to the case of a monic polynomial in $A[t]$. Is there some nice example where we get a non-trivial field extension which can't be expressed using a monic irreducible $f\in A[t]$?

Comment: @KevinCasto Is it a fact that $B$ will necessarily be finite over $A$? If so, is there a standard reference you could point me to? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it seems that given any non-monic polynomial $f = a_nt^n + \cdots + a_0\in A[t]$, which is irreducible in $K[t]$, we can instead look at $g(t) = a_n^{n-1}f(t/a_n)$ which is monic in $A[t]$ and defines the same field extension $L/K$. And then I guess we can take $B$ to be the normalization of this $A[t]/(g)$ (in its function field $L$)? So I suppose my question boils down to having a simple description of normalization, which seems complicated given the examples like $t^2 - x(x-1)^2$ above.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Fair enough, I guess I was implicitly assuming that $f$ was chosen in $A[t]$ so that $A[t]/(f) = B$. (In your example ofc, $A[t]/(f)$ is not integrally closed.)

Comment: @KevinCasto Could you elaborate on what's intuition behind thinking it's always possible to find monic $f\in A[t]$ such that $B = A[t]/(f)$?

Comment: @MohanSwaminathan Oop sorry, this isn't true in general. But it is true for curves, i.e. when $Y$ is 1-dimensional, as in the cases we've been discussing; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9652/is-every-curve-birational-to-a-smooth-affine-plane-curve

Comment: @KevinCasto: I see no reason why $B$ should be generated by a single element over $A$ (this is true locally if $X$ is a curve). Even if it is, it may not have the form $A[u]/(f)$, with just one equation.

Comment: For just the fact that B is finite over A, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/032L